# How do I keep words from being replaced by each button?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, button, label

I am creating an application for class called Sentence Builder, it's supposed to allow the user to click the buttons provided to build a sentence on a label. I have had no success on getting a word generated by a button to stay on the label after I click another button. When I click a button it displays the word on the button onto the label. Then when I click another button, the word on that button appears on the label but it takes the place of the previous word that was already there. I need it to stay on the label so the user can create a sentence on the label by pressing multiple buttons. This is my code for the application.

```
namespace C3_7_Sentence_Builder
{
    public partial class sentencebuilderForm : Form
    {
        public sentencebuilderForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sentenceoutputLabel.Text = "";
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void AButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output;
            output = AButton.Text;
            sentenceoutputLabel.Text = output;
        }

        private void a_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output;
            output = a_Button.Text;
            sentenceoutputLabel.Text = output;
        }

        private void anButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output;
            output = anButton.Text;
            sentenceoutputLabel.Text = output;
        }

        private void TheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output;
            output = TheButton.Text;
            sentenceoutputLabel.Text = output;
        }

        private void the_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output;
            output = the_Button.Text;
            sentenceoutputLabel.Text = output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Text+= output;` - You are reassigning the text, you need to be appending.

Comment: Please note that you could `replace all event method with just one` as posted by @Sayse. I recommend you that. If you don't understand then ask in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `+=`

`sentenceoutputLabel.Text += output;`

what that does is it appends the string instead of overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from my comment, I figured I would post as an answer because you can remove all the individual events and suscribe all your buttons to the following to do the same thing.

```
private void sentence_button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if(button != null)
        sentenceoutputLabel.Text += button.Text;
}
```

The only button that *does* need to reassign the text, instead of appending would be the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

You are always replacing all text of the label with all text of your choice. You need the text of the label to stay and only *add* the new text:

```
sentenceoutputLabel.Text = sentenceoutputLabel.Text + output;
```

You may want to add some spaces:

```
sentenceoutputLabel.Text = sentenceoutputLabel.Text + " " + output;
```